# How / where do I check http-errors when i repeatedly call an API?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I dont know where / how at all to catch http-errors when i repeatedly call an api?

I've been playing around with loading mock images from lorempicsum and of course i'd like to catch http-errors.

I've tried rxjs catchError() inside the method where i make my calls, but then i had to return an of(EMPTY) and it lead me nowhere. Then i realized, that i dont know where is should catch the http-errors, when i am using a pipe operator. Is that even possible? I mean like, if one of five calls fail, catch the error, do something and subscribe to the successful results?

In the end, i would like to display a grey box for every failing call, but i dont know how to get there from here...

Thx

Here is my image service

```
@Injectable()
export class MockImageService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private readonly sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  getRandomImageBlobs(
    numberOfImages: number,
    widthInPx: number,
    heightInPx: number
  ): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get(`https://picsum.photos/${widthInPx}/${heightInPx}/?random`, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' },
        responseType: 'blob'
      })
      .pipe(repeat(numberOfImages));
  }

  getSafeURL(blob: Blob): SafeUrl {
    const objectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const sanitizedObjectURL = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, objectURL);
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
  }
}
```

my component that uses it

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MockImageService } from '../../services/mock-image.service';
import { SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-random-image-display',
  template: `
  <div class="container" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="center" fxLayoutGap="4px">
    <div *ngFor="let url of safeURLs">
      <img [src]="url"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class RandomImagesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() numberOfImages: number;
  @Input() widthInPx: number;
  @Input() heightInPx: number;

  public safeURLs: SafeUrl[] = [];

  constructor(private imgService: MockImageService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // TODO catch invalid formats / http errors!
    this.imgService
      .getRandomImageBlobs(this.numberOfImages, this.widthInPx, this.heightInPx)
      .subscribe((blob: Blob) => {
        this.safeURLs.push(this.imgService.getSafeURL(blob));
      });
  }
}
```

and part of the containing components html

```
<app-random-image-display
  [numberOfImages]="5"
  [widthInPx]="200"
  [heightInPx]="300"
></app-random-image-display>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you create a more centralized error handling mechanism. This can be achieved by an [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor#description). Any HTTP error will trigger the `catchError` method as seen below

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, throwError as observableThrowError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';



@Injectable()
export class MyHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((err: any, caught: Observable<any>) => {

        // Handle the error here

        return observableThrowError(err);
      }));
  }
}
```

Register the Interceptor on the AppModule or CoreModule

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


@NgModule({
  providers: [
      { 
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
        useClass: MyHttpInterceptor, 
        multi: true }
  ]
})
export class CoreModule {
// rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll want to add another callback method inside of the subscribe for getRandomImageBlobs.

```
.getRandomImageBlobs(this.numberOfImages, this.widthInPx, this.heightInPx)
.subscribe((blob: Blob) => {
  this.safeURLs.push(this.imgService.getSafeURL(blob));
}, (error: any) => {
  // handle error
});
```

Comment: @downvotes:
I don't care if you do downvote, but can you please add some details/context or an answer to the question?

Comment: I did not downvote, as i find both answers useful and think the solution will be a combination of both. 
I have found a good article that helped me with my "stragetic"-problem: https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/.
For my problem, i think providing a default value with catchError will be best, therefore i will accept the first answer. But thank you very much anyway!

Comment: I agree the now accepted is closest to the best answer, also thank for that link!